# Eclipse JUnit 4 gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When I try to run a JUnit 4 test i get a NullPointerException in Eclipse. 
JUnit3 though works.

I'm trying the following test class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Test {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Here is the Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localURL(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.entryString(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.addEntry(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate$ClasspathLocalizer.localizeClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspath(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I'm using OS X Snow Leopard with Java SDK 1.6.0_35 (from Apple).
Both JDK and JUnit 4 are in my build path. 
Has the Java Version something to do with the problem ?

UPDATE:

Ok I'm an idiot not thinking of this. I installed Eclipse for C/C++ Developers as I had to do something in C++. But I also used the same instance to develop for Android with the Android SDK plugin and I did some small Java Applications. But I didn't have the Java Development Tools or the Java EE Developer Tools installed. I installed them now and JUnit 4 works now.

I guess one of this Tools is used for JUnit 4. Strange though that JUnit 3 worked. 
Anyway it works now.

Thank you all for your support though.

Comment: Java has so many problems that a simple version upgrade might solve it. As always, it's recommended to use the latest version (especially since they found some major flaws lately).

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: If you're using 3.6 (Helios) and looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/core/3.6.0/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/launcher/JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java#JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate it seems like you've got a corrupted installation of Eclipse. Try using a fresh installation (of Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I'm using Eclipse Juno though.

Comment: It's the same source for juno: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.2/org.eclipse.jdt.junit/core/3.7.100/org/eclipse/jdt/junit/launcher/JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java#JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate

Comment: Does this mean I have to install Eclipse new? I installed quite some plugins also now (Android, C++ etc.) Do I have to reinstall them? How can Eclipse be corrupted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I'm an idiot not thinking of this. I installed Eclipse for C/C++ Developers as I had to do something in C++. But I also used the same instance to develop for Android with the Android SDK plugin and I did some small Java Applications. But I didn't have the Java Development Tools or the Java EE Developer Tools installed. I installed them now and JUnit 4 works now.

Comment: Same problem i had. I had an Eclipse ADT.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problems, I reinstall the ADT from version to 22.3 to 23 because the upgrade issue. It seems that the new version ADT excludes the 'Java Development Tool'.

You can check the 
'Help'->'About'->'Installatoin Details' for details.

So I use the existed Juno upgrade site in eclipse to install the JDT (Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno), after that, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your import org.junit.Test conflicts with the class name. You might want to rename your class Test to e.g. ATest to get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Not yet implemented
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
    at ATest.test(ATest.java:8)
```

Another option might be to put Test in a package (as not to use the default package)

Source code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ATest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

}
```

Tested with Eclipse Juno on Max OS 10.8.0

```
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10-428-10M3811)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.10-b01-428, mixed mode)
```

I am pretty sure this would also work on lion.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang. Thanks a lot for the response. Unfortunately both, renaming the test class to ATest and putting the Test in a package didn't help.

Comment: Please concact me via the contact form of my companies webpage http:/www.bitplan.com. I'll reply with a personal e-mail, try to solve the problem (on the same environment as you: lion, eclipse juno, exact same java version) and post the answer here.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang. Thank you for your support. It works now. See my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, yes, As your UPDATE describes, 
the default is JUnit 4, which haven't installed.
Once changing to JUnit 3, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Neon newly installed, and with ADT (Android, which includes Java, and normally installs Junit).

I just installed JDT (Java Development Tools), and it works well after.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue! Just reset the perspective (Right click->Reset) and it will work!