# NoClassDefFoundError from Robolectric with ADT23 and Android 15

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, adt, robolectric

I have an Android project for which I am trying to setup unit tests using JUnit, Mockito and Robolectric. I'm using ADT23 (this is worth mentionning because I had to manually download eclipse JDT because of that, as per this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25519274/3519951). All of the above running on Windows 7.

When running the tests, I encounter a NoClassDefFoundError error on Android View.

Yes, Android is imported (platform android-15), as well as my Android project... Here are my librairies :

[image: Imported librairies]

Run Configuration :

- Running all tests in the selected project
- Test runner is JUnit 4
- Using Eclipse JUnit Launcher (and **not** Android JUnit Test launcher)
- In the arguments tab, I set working directory to ${workspace_loc:ApplicationLauncherActivity}, which represents my project under test.

Here is the full stack trace :

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/View
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createResourceLoader(RobolectricTestRunner.java:502)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setupApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:357)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.internalBeforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:307)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:285)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: caught an exception while obtaining a class file for android.view.View
    at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:359)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.findClass(RobolectricClassLoader.java:82)
    at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:311)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.RobolectricClassLoader.loadClass(RobolectricClassLoader.java:59)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: problem instrumenting public void android.view.View.setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.fixMethod(AndroidTranslator.java:324)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.fixMethods(AndroidTranslator.java:245)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.onLoad(AndroidTranslator.java:103)
    at javassist.Loader.findClass(Loader.java:340)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:203)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:303)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.compareSignature(MemberResolver.java:247)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:119)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:96)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:704)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:681)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:156)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atArrayInit(TypeChecker.java:185)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.ArrayInit.accept(ArrayInit.java:28)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atNewArrayExpr(TypeChecker.java:161)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atNewExpr(TypeChecker.java:143)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.NewExpr.accept(NewExpr.java:72)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMethodArgs(JvstTypeChecker.java:220)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:702)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:681)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:156)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:45)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:241)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:329)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:350)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:390)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:354)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:350)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:49)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:568)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:705)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:685)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.bytecode.AndroidTranslator.fixMethod(AndroidTranslator.java:321)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:764)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:190)
    ... 57 more
```

A colleage has a similar setup that is currently working, but we couldn't find out any significative difference, except he runs ADT 22.3. Any help appreciated, thank you very much!

**Edit:**
I figured some of you might want to see a test class, here is one. You'll see that there is not even a reference to an Android object in there, so the error is really related with Robolectric's initialisation...

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class BogusTest
{

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
    }

    @Test
    public void theTest()
    {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but any reason why you're using such an old version of Robolectric?

Comment: A good question indeed : With ADT22.3, on my colleague's setup, newer versions of Robolectric would not work. We tried various versions (including the most recent one) of Robolectric with ADT 23, but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

We decided to quit using ADT and install Eclipse Luna with the plugins we needed (Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Native Development Tools). It's not much more complicated than installing ADT and now the tests run fine. That issue will remain unexplained...